# Contact us page error in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I am new to magento, I have installed one extension for captcha in contact us page from http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/contacts-form-captcha.html but it is community addition and mine is enterprise.

When i visit the contact us page it shows the error in index controller in my installed module and after i have removed the folder(recaptcha) from my community folder and related xml files also i have removed. But now it's showing the error like

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setFormAction() on a non-object in /var/www/myapp/app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php on line 55
```

And the code in line 55 is

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('contactForm')->setFormAction(Mage::getUrl('*/*/post'));
```

Please help me to view contact us page.

Comment: check contactForm exits or not in xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the mistake what i did and the problem is in my layouts/contacts.xml file.

I am calling the block in my index controller but that block not existed in layout

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('contactForm')->setFormAction(Mage::getUrl('*/*/post'));
```

'contactForm' block missed in layout

```
    <contacts_index_index translate="label">
            <label>Contact Us Form</label>
            <reference name="head">
                <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="contacts"><title>Contact Us</title></action>
            </reference>
                    <reference name="content">
                <block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml">
            </reference>

 </contacts_index_index>
```

After adding the above code my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the module from admin as well as in the xml file which will be in (`app/etc/modules/namespace_module.xml`) 
clear the magento cache and check. I think it will help you

Answer (score 0):

I am also not an expert but if you have removed all files including xml file in "etc/modules" folder it should work.Try clearing your cache and see what happens.